# Two tables with foreign key referencing the other, NameError

Tags: python, foreign-keys, peewee

I'm trying to create tables with foreign keys in database with peewee.
Player table has ForeignKey to Team table and Team table has ForeignKey to Player table. When i run my code i'm getting
`NameError: name 'Team' is not defined`
Here is my code:

```
class Player(Model):
    nickname = CharField(max_length=30)
    steam_id = CharField(max_length=15)
    team = ForeignKeyField(Team)
    class Meta:
        database = db

class Team(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=30)
    captain = ForeignKeyField(Player)
    class Meta:
        database = db
Player.create_table()
Team.create_table()
```

Can someone help me? :)

Comment: I don't know peewee ònly SQL but you can't set a FK to a "class" / table that doesn't exists in SQL. I think here it's the same. You could try to add the FK after creation of both classes. Beside of this you could do a class `TeamPlayer` where you got 3 attributes: Player, Team and captain. So you avoid the crossing FKs

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer!  `setattr(Team, "captain", ForeignKeyField(Player))`, `setattr(Player, "team", ForeignKeyField(Team))` fixed the problem :)

Comment: This approach is actually not going to work well because of certain hooks that run during metaclass / model class creation. If you want to add a field dynamically instead you should call "field.add_to_class(model_class, field_name)". This will take care of setting the attribute correctly and running the hooks. *The best / correct answer*, however, is listed below in the answers section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this error because you are referencing `Team` in `Player`, before you have defined `Team`. You have a circular dependency here. `Team` is dependent on `Player` and `Player` is dependent on `Team`.

My first suggestion would be to drop one of the dependencies. Do you really need a reference to the other in both tables?

If you do, then the peewee docs has an entire section dedicated to handling this situation: http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/models.html#circular-foreign-key-dependencies

Comment: This isn't an answer, its a link to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DeferredForeignKey this uses the Django style type-as-string approach, but comes with the caveat it won't create your database constraints for you

So for

```
team = ForeignKeyField(Team)
```

use

```
team = DeferredForeignKeyField('Team')
```

and then later

```
db.create_tables([Player,Team])
Player._schema.create_foreign_key(Player.team)
```